# Vanishing electric field inside a conductor implies vanishing charge density but there is a puzzle

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors, metals

If we place a metallic conductor in a static, external electric field, the free electrons inside the conductor will move opposite to the external field leaving the immobile positive ions (nucleus+core electrons) where they are inside the conductor. This will cause an internal field to build up opposite to the external field, and in static equilibrium, they cancel out. This is how the net electric field inside a conductor vanishes, in static equilibrium. **By Gauss' law, $\nabla\cdot{\vec E}=\rho/\varepsilon_0$, it further implies that the charge density $\rho({\vec r})$ also vanishes at every point inside the conductor**.

But after equilibrium is established, let us consider that part of the conductor which contains only immobile positive ions (or certainly a large excess of it). If we now consider a small volume $\Delta V$ in that part of the conductor which contains predominantly immobile positive ions, $\Delta V$ will contain a nonzero positive charge $\Delta q$. When we take the limit $\Delta V\to 0$, we should get, $$\rho(\vec r)=\lim_{\Delta V\to 0}\frac{\Delta q}{\Delta V}\neq 0.$$ The figure below is a rough cartoon of what I mean (after static equilibrium is established).

[image]

What is wrong with the argument in the second paragraph?

Comment: The picture is misleading.

Comment: @my2cts Why? By clue circles with a $`+'$, I represent immobile ions. I didn't show the bound/core electrons separately.

Comment: You picture a solid made up from only positive ions. What does such an impossible solid have to do with a conductor?

Comment: You (accurately) drew equal amounts of positive and negative charges on the surfaces. Why would you assume that the bulk would then be left with an excess of positive charge, when the overall conductor is neutral?

Comment: @my2cts I did not do that. I am considering real solid. Please read my comment above.

Comment: Your picture does not show a real conductor. In the bulk a conductor is neutral, at the relevant length scales.

Comment: Start out by sketching a picture with equal numbers of - and + in total, since the conductor is neutral.

Comment: @Chris The positive charges that I show on the right surface are those of the positive ions on the right surface. I cannot get my head around the fact that immobile ions in the bulk cannot move. They must stay there.

Comment: Where did all the electrons go?

Comment: @my2cts The valence electrons move to the surface while core electrons stay with the nucleus. The circle with the plus sign represents the nuclei with core electrons (i.e. immobile positive ions).

Comment: @Solidification If you are showing positive ions then you need to show an equal number of additional negative charges.

Comment: @Chris This is driving me nuts :-( :-( There are no negative ions. There are electrons and positive ions in solid crystalline metal. No matter what happens on the surface, the atoms inside the lattice positions become unneutralized once the valence electrons move to the surface. How can the charge in $\Delta V$ still remain zero? It's like the outermost $4s$ electrons of the Cu atoms moved to the surface leaving $Cu^+$ ions bare at their lattice positions.

Comment: @Solidification Okay, look at it this way. Count up the total charges you have drawn. What is the *net* charge of that picture? (It's positive). What should it be? (Neutral). How can it be neutral? (Add more electrons). Where can those electrons go while keeping the surface charges balanced as they need to be to cancel out a uniform electric field? (In the bulk).

Comment: @Chris Aha! I think I got it now. Not all the valence electrons in the bulk go to the surface. Valence electrons from a few atomic layers close to the left surface move towards the right surface. Most of the bulk atoms continue to remain neutralized. Am I right?

Comment: @Solidification Yes. Well, more realistically it's probably that all the electrons move over a bit, so some from one surface join the bulk and some from the bulk join the other surface. But the net result is that the bulk atoms are neutral on average.

Comment: @Chris Thank you very much! You saved my day :-) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excess of positive ions is only on the surface, just like the excess of electrons on the other side is only on the surface. The inside of the conductor remains neutral.

Comment: I am not totally convinced. If we apply a strong enough electric field, it is possible that most of the free electrons are driven to one side/surface but leave the bulk of the conductor with bare immobile positive ions. The immobile positive ions of the bulk cannot move to one side in a crystalline conductor.

Comment: @Solidification If there is an excess of positive ions in the bulk of the conductor, then there is an electric field in the conductor. If there is an electric field in the conductor, then the electrons will move until there isn't. If you apply an electric field that is so large that there are *no* electrons left in the conductor, what you have isn't a conductor anymore. It's separate piles of electrons and ions (both of which will react rather explosively).

Comment: If there are only positive ions left there is indeed a field. A field so strong that the solid undergoes Coulomb explosion.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong to mix macroscopic and microscopic descriptions.

The statement that, inside a conductor, the net charge density is zero is valid only at the macroscopic level. There is a non-vanishing local density (positive at the nuclear positions and negative elsewhere due to the electronic density). In the presence of an external electric field, close to parts of the surface, there will be an excess of electrons. Close to other parts, a depletion, manifesting as negatively and positively charged regions on the surface.

At the macroscopic level, the excess and depletion regions are a few atomic layers wide. Therefore, at this level (or better, at the limit of a negligible volume of the surface layers as compared to the bulk volumes), they behave like a *surface charge density*, not as a volume charge density.

Comment: Consider the region $\Delta V$ shown in my diagram, and let us suppose that we do not take the limit $\Delta V\to $atomic volume, but a volume that contains many ions with positive charges. Still $\rho(\vec r)>0$. Why not?

Comment: @Solidification Because it also contains many electrons with negative charges. Exactly as many, on average.

Comment: Dear @GiorgioP If no external field were applied from outside, the net charge inside $\Delta V$ would have been zero. This I agree. But when an external field is applied, the valence/free electrons have moved from the bulk to the surface, hence $\Delta V$ would contain lesser electrons (only core electrons will be there). So don't we expect that $\Delta V$ now has an unneutralized positive charge?

Comment: @Solidification No. The excess electrons on the left side of the metal in your diagram correspond to an absence of exactly as many electrons on the right side. The bulk of the metal remains neutral, there aren't fewer electrons per atom.

Comment: @Solidification, you are still mixing macro- and microscopic views. If $\Delta V$ becomes comparable with the atomic interparticle distance, the net charge is never zero.  Only with a volume larger than the typical interatomic distances, the overall charge will be nearly zero in the  bulk. That's the length scale where it is possible to represent the average charge density as a macroscopically smooth function. In the same limit, at the surface, the charge density becomes a Dirac delta centered at the surface, or, in an equivalent way, a non-vanishing surface charge density.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way. Because of the external field all valence electrons move a little to one side. This causes excess negative charge on one surface and excess positive charge on the opposite. In the bulk the conductor remains neutral.